# How to put a prior on parameter "x" instead of parameter "y" if x and y are related

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

**Background:**

I'm new to the Bayesian approach and thus am trying to better understand the multi-level (i.e., hierarchical) nature of the Bayesian approach.

**Question:**

Suppose I have a parameter called $\delta$. The parameter $\delta$ can be defined as $\delta = \mu / \sigma$.

Why if we place a $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ prior on $\delta$,  this is equivalent to placing a $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ prior on $\mu$?

Comment: This is because mu=delta*sigma and a constant times a random variable has variance equal to the square of the constant.

Comment: What is not clear to you? I think my comment is a formal response. Is it that you don't know why a random variable with variance sigma squared when multiplied by a constant has variance equal to the constant squared times sigma squared?

Comment: If you look at the variance in terms of an integral and recognize tht the integral is linear the result becomes apparent.

Comment: That is not right mu would have variance 4 when delta has variance 2. By the way the only connection with Bayesian methods is that the distribution is a prior. You get the same result taking the classical approach.  There is nothing more that I can say.

Comment: This seems very on-topic; I'm not sure why it was tagged as a software question.

Comment: @gung, I have asked a [**Question HERE**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/how-to-check-confidence-interval-accuracy-on-a-proportion-from-a-binomial-experi), would you mind taking a look at it when get a chance?